# Is there an 1-hour guide at the Deutsches Museum?

Tags: germany, tours, museums, munich, guides

In British Museum, you can get a map (the one with the magnificent Parthenon marbles on the cover) that list the must-see exhibits of the museum in an hour.

Is there something similar in the [Deutsches Museum](https://www.deutsches-museum.de/en) in Munich? I couldn't find any.

Comment: How unfortunate, to spend only an hour in the British Museum. You should try to experience it for real sometime.

Comment: @Sneftel, given that I was on a business trip and sick, I am very glad that managed to squeeze a visit in the British museum. However, I indeed went again, once more while being on a business trip, but that was mostly to check on questions arisen to my mind about the 1h exhibits. I hope that I will be able to visit it again, and pay a more analytical visit to it! :)

Comment: In all museums you can make your own 'one hour' tour, and work it out on your own taste rather than what someone else thinks you may want to see.

Comment: That "someone else" is an expert, and has a better understanding for the museum's exhibits than me @Willeke, surely without my personal taste, but on average, I trust that their advice is worth to-be-followed. I am looking for something **official**, just like the guide in the British museum, rather than my own - or a fellow tourist's - advice. Hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Deutsche Museum has some tour suggestions ([flyer](https://www.deutsches-museum.de/fileadmin/Content/010_DM/010_Information/010_Allgemein/010_Infoflyer/181016_DTM056_Tour_Faltplakat_01_ENG_RZ_digital.pdf), [app](https://www.deutsches-museum.de/en/whats-on/app/)) and the app apparently also has a list of top 10 stations.

The tour suggestions are about 2 h each, but they are composed of several topic tours and demonstrations that you can combine as you wish and as fits into your schedule.

There is also a guided overview tour, again of 2 h.

---

Personally, I'd recommend considering picking a topic that interests you and take the demonstration/tour plus some further time in that part.

Most tours are by default in German, but they give a [list of tours/demonstrations that they consider basically language independent (scroll to end of page)](https://www.deutsches-museum.de/en/whats-on/guided-tours/red-dot/).

Personally, I recommend the high-voltage or glass blowing demonstration (though it's years that I've been there).

Comment: The only thing that arrived to my ears is Enigma in this museum. Thank you very, much, just looking on how to get there from Munich Main station, thanks - I am visiting tomorrow! :)

Comment: Nooo! Planetarium:Due to maintenance the planetarium will be closed from November 25 to 29, 2019. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: @gsamaras: tough luck :( the planetarium *is* nice.

Comment: Good thing that I've visited a nice planetarium in Athens. I think I'll go for High Voltage and Microscopy Theater demos, and then towards Enigma! You mentioned Glass blowing demo - where in the flyer is that belonging?

Comment: Glass is on level 2: https://www.deutsches-museum.de/fileadmin/Content/010_DM/010_Information/010_Allgemein/010_Infoflyer/6_2019_EN_Site_Map.pdf (but I may be a bit biased towards glass blowing as I'm chemist)

Comment: Thanks cbeleites, χημεία is cool! I remember being taught about it from Empedocles and Democritus perspectives. Your answer was just in time, thank you so much, cheers!

Comment: **MICROSCOPY THEATRE** demo the highlight of the museum!

Comment: @gsamaras Tram 17 from either central station north (Hauptbahnhof Nord) or central station (Hauptbahnhof) directly to Deutsches Museum.

Comment: Yes @Jan, I went yesterday, I found the tram convenient.